# mailto doesnt work with android how to solve this?

Tags: html, mailto

Im really stuck on this one, I want people to click on a button and email the url with parameters in the body of an email. It works fine on Desktop, laptop but on mobile devices it doesnt sent the parameters.

WORKING: 
http://www.terbruggenantiek.nl/?page=details&id=21

NOT WORKING (mobile devices):
http://www.terbruggenantiek.nl/?page

My Code:

```
<?php
  $encoded_url = urlencode( getUrl() );
?>

<a href="mailto:(hidden)@gmail.com?subject=Geinteresseerd in deze advertentie&body=<?php echo  $encoded_url; ?>" title="Advertentie" target="_blank" class="btn btn-email"><i class="fa fa-email"></i> Reageer nu</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add data-rel="external" to your link tag:

```
<a href="mailto:(hidden)@gmail.com?subject=Geinteresseerd in deze advertentie&body=<?php echo  $encoded_url; ?>" title="Advertentie" data-rel="external" target="_blank" class="btn btn-email"><i class="fa fa-email"></i> Reageer nu</a>
```

Comment: Your site works on my phone... What phone are you trying this with?